# Link to a file in nginx autoindex not correct

Tags: nginx, hyperlink, character-encoding, windows-xp

My configuration currently looks like this:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    include        win-utf;
    include        koi-win;
    include        koi-utf;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;


        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

    location /autoindex {
            autoindex on;
            charset utf-8;

        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

And I have a file with the title `Was Alkohol mit deinem Körper macht.lrc` in the html subfolder autoindex the lintext is: `Was Alkohol mit deinem Körper ma..>` and the link is `http://localhost/autoindex/Was%20Alkohol%20mit%20deinem%20K%F6rper%20macht.lrc` But when I click it "An error occurred." happens. If I go back and change `%F6` to `ö` or `%C3%B6`, I can get to the file. But what do I have to do, to not have to change anything? Or is this an unresolvable issue? I have a feeling this has something to do with the charsets.

My OS: Windows XP

My nginx version 1.9.12 (most recent at time of post)

Comment: Just bypassing this in revue... it seems maybe more like a client problem?
Client not handling things correctly maybe?
IIRC it was an old version of UC's mobile browser that was malfunctioning.